# ECharts - enable tooltip for every data point, but skip xAxis labels

Tags: javascript, echarts

Not sure whether this will get answered, since ECharts isn't popular relative to other charting libraries, but here I go.

There is an example chart

http://ecomfe.github.io/echarts/doc/example/axis.html#-en

Now what I want to do is, enable every point as a tooltip, but skip the displaying of xAxis labels.

So, I can display all the tooltips by setting

```
  xAxis : [{
    axisLabel:{
      interval:0
    }
  }]
```

That works well. But it also shows every xAxis label. I want to display every 2nd xAxis label, so if I change to

```
  xAxis : [{
    axisLabel:{
      interval:1
    }
  }]
```

Now I only see tooltips of every 2nd data point.

Is there a way to enable tooltip for every data point but skip the labels as I wish?

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you say every point as a tooltip means tooltip will appear when mouse hovered on a bar of bar chart, or a circle symbol of line chart. If so, you can change the tooltip trigger to 'item'.

```
tooltip : {
    trigger: 'item'
},
```